# How to display the PHP multiple dimensional associative array in html table?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table, associative-array

Below is my multiple dimensional associative array.

```
   <?php

$city = array(
    "schoolDetails" => array(
        "schoolOne" => array(
            "schoolName" => "TCS",
            "branchName" => "Iqbal Campus",
            "phone"      => "4256791",
            "numberOfTeachers" => 50,
            "departments" => array(
                "Maths",
                "English",
                "Science",
                "Computer"
            ),
            "teachers" => array(
                "Mr Ali",
                "Mr Waseem",
                "Mr Kashif",
                "Mr Adeel"
            )
        ),

        "schoolTwo" => array(
            "schoolName" => "CSS",
            "branchName" => "Gohdpur Campus",
            "phone"      => "4261201",
            "numberOfTeachers" => 30,
            "departments" => array(
                "Islamiyat",
                "Pakistan Studies",
                "Urdu",
                "Arts"
            ),
            "teachers" => array(
                "Mr Naeem",
                "Mr Waris",
                "Mr Kamran",
                "Mr Aleem"
            )
        )
    )
);
?>
```

I am confused about how to display the result in tabular form in html. As well as how to echo the code.
The way I tried to output the result is

```
    foreach ($city as $school ) {
    # code...
    foreach ($school as $schools ) {
        # code...
        foreach ($schools as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

But in this my department and teachers index are not printed. So how to access them and print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all get the headlines
- Then iterate thru the schools
- Output the columns with their contents

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>";
foreach (array_keys(reset($city['schoolDetails'])) as $headline) {
    echo "<th>$headline</th>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

foreach ($city['schoolDetails'] as $school) {
    echo "<tr>";
    displayColumn($school);
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

function displayColumn(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo implode("<br>\n", $value);
        } else {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
}
```

[image: ResultTable]

Comment: How I can show each department separately? Like one column shows maths and next to it show its corresponding HOD Mr Ali

Comment: The data structure given separated department from teachers. It would be better if a department has 1-n teachers. Then it would make sense to colspan or put a table inside department. With the given data, you can use a if clause.